# how to set value and have the right option 'selected" in a select box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that is used to populate a select box :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //populate site list.
    $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo site_url('site/sitelist');?>",
              type:'POST',
              dataType:'json',
              success: function(res) {
            //loop through results
            var htmlstring = "<option value='' disabled selected>Select the Site</option>";
            for (var key in res) {
            if (res.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    //console.log(key + " -> " + res[key]['site_abbrev']);
                    htmlstring += "<option value=" + res[key]['site_abbrev'] + ">" + res[key]['name'] + "</option>";
                }
             }
             $('#site').append(htmlstring); 
              }, 
          error: function(xhr, req, err) {
             var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
             console.log(err.Message);
          }
    });

    var $site_val = $('#hidden_site').val();
    console.log($site_val);
    if ($site_val !== 'undefined') {
        $('#site').val($site_val);  
    }


});
```

And this is the static HTML code I start out with:

```
   <!--use to populate select after form is displayed -->
     <input type="hidden" id="hidden_site" name="hidden_site" value="<?php echo($details['site']);?>"/>                                             
      <select class="form-control" placeholder="Site:" name="site" id="site">
     </select>
```

When i run this code, I can see "CAN" print in the console as the val of the variable that contains my site info 
But I can't seem to get it to select the "canada" option (which has the value of "CAN") from the drop down.

**EDIT 1**

The code won't work but in the console I tried this:

```
 $("#site option[value='CAN'").prop('selected',true)
```

to prove that "Canada" has a value of CAN.  And now i see the Canada option selected.  But none of the answer posted so far are working for me. 
:/

I also tried both of these:

```
    $('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    //$('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

**EDIT 2**

This version also fails.

```
var $site_val = $('#hidden_site').val();
console.log($site_val);  //prints CAN
if ($site_val !== 'undefined') {
    $('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').change();      
    //$('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    //$('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
}
```

Comment: Try $('#site option[value="'+$site_val+'"]')

Comment: do you want to select the option with some value OR set a selectbox value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes I want to select an option using the value.  So I have an option called "Canada" with the value "CAN".  I want to have Canada be the selected option...

Comment: why are the options outside of `select` element?

Comment: they aren't.  I just cut a portion of the select box html code bcause the list was super long.  sorry about that.  but the select box appears correctly, is populated correctly... and now I just need to select using the value stored in my variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to set the value of a select box using a variable

I suppose, you are actually trying to select the option that has a specified value, use the following approach:

```
// to remove previously selected option, at first
$('option:selected', 'select[name="site"]').removeAttr('selected');

$('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

In some cases, the following also should work:

```
$('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

Also you should move your *"selecting"* code into `success` callback function right after appending, because `$.ajax` method works asynchronously. So it should look like:

```
...
$('#site').append(htmlstring);
var $site_val = $('#hidden_site').val();
console.log($site_val);  //prints CAN
if ($site_val !== 'undefined') {   
    $('option:selected', 'select[name="site"]').removeAttr('selected');
    $('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    //$('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
} 
...
```

Comment: that's not working for some reason. I'm going to add the HTML showing the select controll... in case I'm missing something that you will see.

Comment: Please see my "EDIT 1"

Comment: I reposted all the code so hopefully it's clearer / easier to see my bug.

Comment: hey there.  neither one is working.  so bizzare!  no errors.  and it works for me in the console.

Comment: you should move your "selecting" code into `success` callback function right after appending, because `$.ajax` method works asynchronously

Comment: bingo.  i should have remembered that.  ugh!  Thanks!!!  Can you modify your answer and I will accept?

Comment: @Happydevdays, welcome, have you tried to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/94Lb36uv/2/)

`$('#site').val($site_val)` -> if you want to set the option by value.

**Correcting your code**

Since `$site_val` is a `variable name`, you have to use it's `value`. Use string concatenation like below.

`$('#site option[value="' + $site_val + '"]').prop('selected', true)` - This will select the option which already has the value `CAN`.

Comment: so no more error message but the "Canada" option (that has value of CAN) is not set on the form.

Comment: @Happydevdays - also added a demo.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to do this with javascript as well. Here is the jquery way.

Just set the value like so:

```
$("#whatever").val('value goes here');
```

Additionally, here's a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/CpXVB/

It's fairly simple to do. I hope that helps. Please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.